# Exiting/breaking loop when there is an empty Curl response

Tags: php, api, curl

So im looping to surveyGizmo, retrieving results. Since they only allow 500 responses per cURL response, I have to keep looping until there is an empty response. So a rough outline of my code looks like this:

```
    $pageIndex = 1;
    while ($pageIndex) {
        $outputGizmo = getSurveyResponse($method = 'GET', $pageIndex);
            if ($outputGizmo == '') {
                break;
            }

        foreach($outputGizmo->data as $surveyResponse) {
            $firstName = $surveyResponse->{'[question(2)]'};
            $lastName = $surveyResponse->{'[question(10)]'};
            $email = $surveyResponse->{'[question(3)]'};
            $phone = $surveyResponse->{'[question(5)]'};
            $postcode = $surveyResponse->{'[question(6)]'};

            // Add to local database will happen here

        }


        $pageIndex += 1;


    }
```

I am getting lost in my loops, and I simply wish to terminate the while loop, when the getSurveyResponse function returns empty. I chose empty because if there are no more responses, it returns literally a blank page.

UPDATE:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (6) {
 ["result_ok"]=>
bool(true)
 ["total_count"]=>
 string(1) "1"
  ["page"]=>
 string(1) "2"
 ["total_pages"]=>
int(1)
 ["results_per_page"]=>
 string(3) "100"
 ["data"]=>
 array(0) {
 }
}
```

Comment: What you have looks like it ought to work, _if_ `$outputGizmo == ''`. That is, if the response is truly an empty string. Since your subsequent loop uses `$outputGizmo->data`, that kind of implies that `$outputGizmo` isn't a string.  Do a `var_dump($outputGizmo)` on the empty response to see what it actually contains.

Comment: the "empty response" probably still has some type of response. I would assume that it will return some type of error message or error code, you should check for that instead of an empty string.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you were right, a var_dump showed a partial response, i will play around with this.

Comment: @kennypu there is no error code in the response, just a few empty array fields

Comment: See updated response above. Any ideas what would be a good check to break?

Comment: @RHK-S8 see below. It's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no more results are available, what you're getting is not actually an empty string, but an object with limited data. Since an empty response returns the `$data` property as an array with zero elements, you only need to test `empty($outputGizmo->data)` to exit your loop:

From your `var_dump()`:

```
["data"]=>
array(0) {
}
```

Break when the array is empty. The rest of your code appears as though it will work as is.

```
if (empty($outputGizmo->data)) {
    break;
}
```